# How to include var in partials calls

Tags: assemble

Let's say I have a website where for each main section I have a specific sidebar.

Currently I have a single sidebar file, where im using categories to filter the correct content to show like this:

```
   {{#inArray page.categories "Components"}}
    <section class="sg-index">
    <ul>
      <li {{#is title "DetailContent"}} class="active"{{/is}}>
        <a href="c-DetailContent.html">DetailContent</a>
      </li>
```

However my goal is to have these sidebar files located at each section folder, along with the section files.

How can I include the {{dirname}} variable in the partials call {{> sidebar}}?

Comment: Are you trying to make a sidebar.hbs partial inside each section folder? Or are you trying to call the sidebar partial passing in data based on that section?

Comment: The goal was to have the sidebar include call a different path according to the active section.

Comment: I'm a little confused, I think I have an idea of what you're trying to accomplish, but there are so many nuances with Handlebars and Assemble that you're unlikely to get a quality answer without more detail. I would suggest either adding a few sections in the code example, along with another code example showing the desired output, or create a gist and link to it. I suspect there are easier ways to go about this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible with a conditional block helper, like `{{with}}` and the [include helper](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helper-include),

B you could also create a custom helper, something like this:

```
var path = require('path');
var _ = require('lodash');
var matter = require('gray-matter');

module.exports.register = function (Handlebars, options, params) {

  var assemble = params.assemble;
  var grunt = params.grunt;
  var opts = options || {};

  Handlebars.registerHelper('sidenav', function(page, context) {
    if(page.published !== false && page.sidenav) {

      if(!Array.isArray(assemble.partials)) {
        assemble.partials = [assemble.partials];
      }

      var filepath = _.first(_.filter(assemble.partials, function(fp) {
        return path.basename(fp, path.extname(fp)) === page.sidenav;
      }));

      // Process context, using YAML front-matter,
      // grunt config and Assemble options.data
      var pageObj = matter(filepath) || {};
      var metadata = pageObj.context || {};

      context = _.extend(this, opts.data[page.sidenav], metadata, context);
      var partial = Handlebars.partials[page.sidenav];
      var template = Handlebars.compile(partial);
      var output = template(context);

      // Prepend output with the filepath to the original partial
      // for debugging
      var sidenav = opts.sidenav || opts.data.sidenav || {};
      if(sidenav.origin === true) {
        output = '<!-- ' + filepath + ' -->\n' + output;
      }
      return new Handlebars.SafeString(output);
    }
  });
};
```

then use it in your markup like this:

```
<div class="sidebar" role="complementary">
  <ul class="nav sidenav">
    {{sidenav this}}
  </ul>
</div>
```